# How can I delete someone from a Google Plus Circle?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-circles

I've tried repeatedly to remove someone from one of my circles and every time they reappear. This is getting very frustrating. I follow the normal process to remove them but they just won't go away. Is there something I'm missing? I've had no problems with removing other members in this or any other circle.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove someone from your circles, it means you won't see any posts from them on your stream(unless someone you follow shares their post with you).

It simply means you don't follow the person anymore, but that person is still able to see your posts and based on your settings the person may be allowed to comment on your posts.

If you **don't want to see anything** from a person (no comments, no posts, no nothing), you should **block** that person.

Please refer to https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047934?hl=en to see details on how you can block someone.

And please note, sometimes you add people to more than just one circle. If you want to remove a person completely, you should remove them from all of your circles.

If you want to see what person is added to which circle I know two ways:

1. go to your circles and find the person you want information about, and hover mouse pointer over their profile picture. The circles which that person is a member of, will glow. Then you can remove this person from all of those circles.
2. When you see a post from a person you don't want to follow, hover mouse pointer over his name and a box appears. If you have the person in any of your circles, there will be a green button that tells you the number of circles this person is a member of.If you hover mouse pointer on it, you can remove that person from your circles.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who was going insane over this stupid limitation thanks to the geniuses in Google, I've finally was able to solve this problem. Unfortunately, my method involved two different steps so I'm not sure which worked:

1. I deleted ALL emails associated with the contact's email; and
2. blocked the contact **via the original circles email telling me the contact added me to his circle**.

Initially, I just deleted him from my circles, but google persistently showed him as still being in my circles, even though he was no longer in my circles. I thought maybe google needed some time to process my request, so I decided to give it a day. Well, it didn't work, so I was back to square one. Next, I searched for the person's profile via circles, and then blocked him there. Didn't work either.

I scoured the internet but wasn't able to find a single viable solution....then one of the users on gmail posted what worked for them, one of the steps being deleting all emails associated with that contact.

I'm not sure which worked, but you can always save the emails elsewhere and then block the contact the way I did, if you still have the original email telling you you were added to the contact's circles.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following.

1. [Block the person](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047934?hl=en)
2. Click *Actions* on your Circles page, then select *View blocked*.
3. Click Unblock.

Now you can add them back to whatever circle you want to.

Answer (score 0):

To remove someone from all of your circles:

- Open Google+.
- Place your cursor in the top left corner for the
  Google+ main menu.
- Click People.
- Click Your circles at the top.
- Enter
  the person's name in the "Type a name" field.
- Place your cursor over
  the tile of the person you wish to remove.
- Click the X.

Source : [Google Support](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1348614?hl=en)